# Skipped 98 frames при скролле ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Не могу понять везде пишут что это из за `getView`. Но в моем то случае я не беру тексты или картинки с интернета или с базы `Sqlite`, данные отправляются уже готовыми в адаптер. Но все равно каждый раз это выскакивает и `listview` подпрыгивает.

**Вот сам адаптер:**

```
public class RubricsResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<VacancyModel> rubricsResutList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    int selectedStr;

    public RubricsResultAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<VacancyModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        rubricsResutList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }

    //Finding textViews and inserting data into them
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
//            holder.checkBox.setChecked(isViewed.get(position));
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.tvProfession = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvProfessionRub);
            holder.tvProfile = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvProfileNameRub);
            holder.Salary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvSalaryRub);
            holder.tvPostCr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvPostCrRub);
            holder.logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(id.ivVacSourceRub);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(id.cbxRub);
            holder.vacancyViewed = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(id.viewedLayoutRub);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);//Due to this line, the star is not changing after scrolling.
//            holder.checkBox.setChecked(isViewed.get(position))
        }

        holder.tvProfession.setText(rubricsResutList.get(position).getProfession());
        holder.tvProfile.setText(rubricsResutList.get(position).getProfile());
        holder.Salary.setText(rubricsResutList.get(position).getSalary());
        holder.tvPostCr.setText(rubricsResutList.get(position).getDate());

        String sourceName = rubricsResutList.get(position).getSiteAddress();
        switch (sourceName) {
            case JSONKeyNames.KEY_HH:
                holder.logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_hh);
                break;
            case JSONKeyNames.KEY_DIESEL:
                holder.logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_diesell);
                break;
            case JSONKeyNames.KEY_DOSKA:
                holder.logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_doska);
                break;
            case JSONKeyNames.KEY_24:
                holder.logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_twenty_four);
                break;
            case JSONKeyNames.KEY_GAZETA:
                holder.logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_gazeta);
                break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvProfession;
        private TextView tvProfile;
        private TextView Salary;
        private TextView tvPostCr;
        private CheckBox checkBox;
        private LinearLayout vacancyViewed;
        private ImageView logo;
    }

}
```

**Вот фрагмент где адаптер вызывается:**

```
public class RubricsResultFragment extends Fragment {

    RubricsResultAdapter adapter;
    public static List<VacancyModel> rubricsResultList;
    public static List<VacancyModel> subRubricsResultList;
    ListView listView;
    SwipyRefreshLayout swipyRefreshLayout;
    String expandAdapterText;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rubics_result_layout, container, false);

        //creating listView for vacancies
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvRubricsResultFragment);

        adapter = new RubricsResultAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.rubrics_result_row, rubricsResultList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Ошибка:** `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-15 15:19:04.511 293-297/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 632K, 17% free 10899K/13063K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 19ms`

**вопрос:** По моему все правильно, но почему эта ошибка выходит и как исправить?

Comment: может большой текст в одном из TextView?

Comment: в качестве оптимизации можете не вызывать каждый раз rubricsResutList.get(position), а инициализировать объект  и у него брать нужные поля

Comment: @metalurgus, нет, везде одинаково

Comment: @s_klepcha, я понял логику, но как вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Я спросил, не одинако во ли в них текста, а много ли. Одинаково много, или одинаково мало?

Comment: Извините, одинаково мало)

Comment: VacancyModel model = rubricsResutList.get(position);

Comment: вы можете расставить логи после каждой строчки, и замерять, какая именно строчка занимает больше всего времени

Comment: @s_klepcha, странно во всех адаптерах прописал как вы сказали,  3 раза уменьшились лаги)), в нескольких местах еще остались) спасибо

Comment: @metalurgus, а как в логах ставить время?

Comment: А зачем? в логах же выводится время самого лога

Comment: Понял, попробую..

Comment: Ну что, выяснили, в чем проблема?

Comment: ну так закомтите ваш `switch` и посмотрите на результат, операции с картинками ведь самые ресурсоемкие.